# I'm trying to my form Insert into SQL Server but I got this error "Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string"

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server

> Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string

I'm using AjaxToolkit for date. My code is like following:

```
  try
        {
            SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection();
            con.ConnectionString = " Server=localhost\\SQLExpress; Database=ins;        Trusted_Connection =True;";

            con.Open();

            CultureInfo cultureInfo = new CultureInfo("en-US");
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("Insert Into damage(Company,DocType,PolicyNumber,DamageType,IncidentLocation,Claiment,DateOfLoss,DateOfNotificationDepartmant,DateOfNotificationtoAgency,OutstandingLoss,ClaimSummary,IncidentReferenceNo,RecordDatebyInsurer,DateofSurvey,IssueDateofSurveyorsDamageReport,TotalIncurred,Indemnity,Deductible,DateofIndemnityPayment,Status,PerformanceRatingofInsuranceDepartmant,PerformanceRatingofAgency,PerformanceRatingofInsuranceCompany1,PerformanceRatingofInsuranceCompany2,TotalLeadTime,LossRatio,IncidentFormNo) VALUES (@Company,@DocType,@PolicyNumber,@DamageType,@IncidentLocation,@Claiment,@DateOfLoss,@DateOfNotificationDepartmant,@DateOfNotificationtoAgency,@OutstandingLoss,@ClaimSummary,@IncidentReferenceNo,@RecordDatebyInsurer,@DateofSurvey,@IssueDateofSurveyorsDamageReport,@TotalIncurred,@Indemnity,@Deductible,@DateofIndemnityPayment,@Status,@PerformanceRatingofInsuranceDepartmant,@PerformanceRatingofAgency,@PerformanceRatingofInsuranceCompany1,@PerformanceRatingofInsuranceCompany2,@TotalLeadTime,@LossRatio,@IncidentFormNo)", con);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Company", TextBox1.Text);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@DocType", TextBox2.Text);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@PolicyNumber", TextBox3.Text);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@DamageType", TextBox4.Text);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@IncidentLocation", TextBox5.Text);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Claiment", TextBox6.Text);
            //DateTime date = DateTime.ParseExact(TextBox7.Text, "M/d/yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@DateOfLoss", DateTime.ParseExact(TextBox7.Text, "m/d/yyyy", System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture));
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@DateOfNotificationDepartmant", DateTime.ParseExact(TextBox8.Text, "m/d/yyyy", System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture));
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@DateOfNotificationtoAgency", DateTime.ParseExact(TextBox9.Text, "m/d/yyyy", System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture));
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@OutstandingLoss", TextBox10.Text);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ClaimSummary", TextBox11.Text);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@IncidentReferenceNo", TextBox12.Text);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@RecordDatebyInsurer", DateTime.ParseExact(TextBox13.Text, "m/d/yyyy", System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture));
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@DateofSurvey", DateTime.ParseExact(TextBox14.Text, "m/d/yyyy", System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture));
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@IssueDateofSurveyorsDamageReport", DateTime.ParseExact(TextBox15.Text, "m/d/yyyy", System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture));
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@TotalIncurred", TextBox16.Text);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Indemnity", TextBox17.Text);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Deductible", TextBox18.Text);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@DateofIndemnityPayment", DateTime.ParseExact(TextBox19.Text, "m/d/yyyy", System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture));
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Status", TextBox20.Text);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@PerformanceRatingofInsuranceDepartmant", TextBox21.Text);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@PerformanceRatingofAgency", TextBox22.Text);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@PerformanceRatingofInsuranceCompany1", TextBox23.Text);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@PerformanceRatingofInsuranceCompany2", TextBox24.Text);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@TotalLeadTime", TextBox25.Text);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@LossRatio", TextBox26.Text);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@IncidentFormNo", TextBox27.Text);

            int rowsaffected = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

            if (rowsaffected == 1)
            {
                Label1.Text = "Damage ticket has been delivered.";
            }
            else
            {
                Label1.Text = "Damage ticket has been not delivered.";
            }

            con.Close();
        }
                catch (Exception a)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("{0} Exception caught.", a);
        }
```

When I'am debugging values for Textbox7.text is shown on addwatch like: 7/14/2014

Staacktrace is like following:

```
    {System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException (0x80131904): Conversion failed when converting            date and/or time from character string.
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.OnError(SqlException exception, Boolean   breakConnection, Action`1 wrapCloseInAction)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnection.OnError(SqlException exception, Boolean breakConnection, Action`1 wrapCloseInAction)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.ThrowExceptionAndWarning(TdsParserStateObject stateObj, Boolean callerHasConnectionLock, Boolean asyncClose)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.TryRun(RunBehavior runBehavior, SqlCommand cmdHandler, SqlDataReader dataStream, BulkCopySimpleResultSet bulkCopyHandler, TdsParserStateObject stateObj, Boolean& dataReady)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.FinishExecuteReader(SqlDataReader ds, RunBehavior runBehavior, String resetOptionsString)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteReaderTds(CommandBehavior cmdBehavior, RunBehavior runBehavior, Boolean returnStream, Boolean async, Int32 timeout, Task& task, Boolean asyncWrite, SqlDataReader ds)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteReader(CommandBehavior cmdBehavior, RunBehavior runBehavior, Boolean returnStream, String method, TaskCompletionSource`1 completion, Int32 timeout, Task& task, Boolean asyncWrite)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.InternalExecuteNonQuery(TaskCompletionSource`1 completion, String methodName, Boolean sendToPipe, Int32 timeout, Boolean asyncWrite)
  at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.ExecuteNonQuery()
  at Test.WebForm2.Button2_Click(Object sender, EventArgs e) in         c:\Users\HASAN\Documents\Visual Studio 2013\Projects\Test\Test\New       Damage\WebForm2.aspx.cs:line 65
ClientConnectionId:90c6e096-88e8-4634-9d40-8bdfa5474292}
```

Comment: Shouldn't that be `M/dd/yyyy`?

Comment: `TextBox1.Text, TextBox2.Text...` Think of the poor soul that has to maintain this and use meaningful names. On topic, it looks like the date format you've provided to `ParseExact` isn't quite right.

Comment: This isn't a bug. This is your fault.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is here:

```
DateTime.ParseExact(TextBox7.Text, "m/d/yyyy", System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)
```

`m` is for minutes and `M` is for months. So, change the format string to `MM/dd/yyyy`

Comment: I do it what you said but ım getting same error like: Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string.

Comment: Updated my answer. Please try now

Comment: Im getting fail in here : cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@DateOfLoss", DateTime.ParseExact(TextBox7.Text, "MM/dd/yyyy", System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)); Fail:"String was not recognized as a valid DateTime."

Comment: Yes I try that Fail is : Im getting fail in here : cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@DateOfLoss", DateTime.ParseExact(TextBox7.Text, "MM/dd/yyyy", System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)); Fail:"String was not recognized as a valid DateTime."

Comment: Does `TextBox7.Text` have any whitespaces?

Comment: There is no whitespaces.

Comment: I've solved this problem. It's like = cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@DateOfLoss",TextBox7.Text);